# No tests found when using ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR

Tags: android, android-testing, android-test-orchestrator

When I have `ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR` in `testOptions`

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    animationsDisabled = true
    execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
}
```

and I run the instrumented test

```
./gradlew connectedStudioDebugAndroidTest --stacktrace
```

I get error that tests are not found

```
com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[emu1(AVD) - 9] FAILED 
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
```

and when I comment out `ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR` in `testOptions`

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    animationsDisabled = true
    // execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
}
```

the tests run.

So how can I get tests to run with `ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR`?

**edit**

I made some progress: the androidTests run on my real device (API 28) but not any emulator (API 28). I'm on OSX btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR` version `1.2.0` and older.

I got it to work by bumping the version to `1.3.0-rc01` in the `dependencies` in the `build.gradle` file.

```
androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.3.0-rc01'
```

Comment: I have `androidTestImplementation deps.testx.orchestrator` should it be `androidTestUtil`?

Comment: according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator) yes. I'm not familiar with `androidTestImplementation deps.testx.orchestrator` so I can't say if that serves a differente purpose or not.

Comment: Your solution worked, but oddly when I switched back to 2.0 and androidTestImplementation, the tests still ran ... however, this is the first time the tests have run at all in the past couple of days, so checkmark.