# No tests found when enable ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR(1.4.0)

Tags: android, android-testing, android-test-orchestrator

I've read [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62395286/no-tests-found-when-using-androidx-test-orchestrator)

However, I'm using the `'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.0'`, which should not has the bug below 1.2.0.

My case is, I will get error: `com.android.build.gradle.internal.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[GM1910 - 11] FAILED` if I enable :

```
    testOptions {
        execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
    }
```

I've done the prefix operations:

```sh
$ curl -O https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/androidx/test/orchestrator/1.4.0/orchestrator-1.4.0.apk

$ curl -O https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/androidx/test/services/test-services/1.4.0/test-services-1.4.0.apk

$ adb install -r orchestrator-1.4.0.apk

$ adb install -r test-services-1.4.0.apk

$ adb shell 'CLASSPATH=$(pm path androidx.test.services) app_process / \
                              androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain am instrument -w -e \
                              targetInstrumentation com.example.notroid/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner \
                              androidx.test.orchestrator/.AndroidTestOrchestrator'


Time: 0

OK (0 tests)
```